# Replace route parameter for dispatch

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

Using RESTful Resource Controllers lets me do this:

```
$request = Request::create(route('api.v1.booking.show'), 'GET');
```

And the decoded generated URL is:

```
http://example.app/api/v1/booking/{booking}
```

I know I could issue a GET request and resolve the parameter calling

```
Route::get($request, function($booking) {
    return $some_id;
});
```

But in my case, I want to forward the request using the dispatch method:

```
return Route::dispatch($request);
```

I cannot figure out how to resolve the parameter when calling the `dispatch` method, since it does not accept a Closure, like the `get` method does.

Aside from using PHP's `str_replace`, is there a Laravel way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're asking about how to set a value of the $booking parameter in the request that is then passed to Route::dispatch()?

Comment: The dispatch method forwards the request to the URL that I indicated in the question, and I need to replace the placeholder `{booking}` with a certain id. This is documented in the Laravel site: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters for get requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set a value to route's **{booking}** parameter, you need to pass an array of route parameters as a second argument of **route()**:

```
$request = Request::create(
  route('api.v1.booking.show', ['booking' => $bookingId]),
 'GET'
);
```